# Oracle Translate function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to Oracle and am trying achieve the following.

I have a column called as USER_NAME which will be in the form a XXXX_YYYY_ZZZZ, where XXXX are numbers, Y and Z are alpha characters. I need to translate that to YYYY_XXXX_ZZZZ.

I did some research and came accros Translate function. Can some one please provide me a sample example how to get the above form?

Comment: You don't want TRANSLATE. Look at regexp_replace.

Comment: If XXXX and YYYY have constant lengths you can do it faster with function SUBSTR().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace('XXXX_YYYY_ZZZZ', '^(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)$', '\2_\1_\3') 
from dual
```